# Expected Behaviour of Compound _id in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a compound _id containing 3 numeric properties:

_id": {
     "KeyA": 0,
     "KeyB": 0,
     "KeyC": 0
  }

The database in question has 2 million identical values for KeyA and clusters of 500k identical values for KeyB.

My understanding is that I can efficiently query for KeyA and KeyB using the command:

```
find( { "_id.KeyA" : 1, "_id.KeyB": 3 } ).limit(100)
```

When I explain this query the result is:

```
"cursor" : "BasicCursor",
"nscanned" : 1000100,
"nscannedObjects" : 1000100,
"n" : 100,
"millis" : 1592,
"nYields" : 0,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"isMultiKey" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"indexBounds" : {}
```

Without the limit() the result is:

```
"cursor" : "BasicCursor",
"nscanned" : 2000000,
"nscannedObjects" : 2000000,
"n" : 500000,
"millis" : 3181,
"nYields" : 0,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"isMultiKey" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"indexBounds" : {}
```

As I understand it BasicCursor means that index has been ignored and both queries have a high execution time - even when I've only requested 100 records it takes ~1.5 seconds. It was my intention to use the limit to implement pagination but this is obviously too slow.

The command:

```
find( { "_id.KeyA" : 1, "_id.KeyB": 3, , "_id.KeyC": 1000 } )
```

Correctly uses the BtreeCursor and executes quickly suggesting the compound _id is correct.

I'm using the release 1.8.3 of MongoDb. Could someone clarify if I'm seeing the expected behaviour or have I misunderstood how to use/query the compound index?

Thanks,
Paul.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The index is not a *compound* index, but an index on the whole value of the `_id` field. MongoDB does not look into an indexed field, and instead uses the raw BSON representation of a field to make comparisons (if I read the docs correctly).

To do what you want you need an actual compound index over `{_id.KeyA: 1, _id.KeyB: 1, _id.KeyC: 1}` (which also should be a unique index). Since you can't not have an index on `_id` you will probably be better off leaving it as `ObjectId` (that will create a smaller index and waste less space) and keep your `KeyA`, `KeyB` and `KeyC` fields as properties of your document. E.g. `{_id: ObjectId("xyz..."), KeyA: 1, KeyB: 2, KeyB: 3}`

Comment: Theo - thanks whilst you answer is essentially the same as mstreams I've accepted your answer because you explicitly pointed out that the _id field wasn't giving me a compound index (which was the bit I was failing to grasp). I'd naively assumed that if I created a compound key on the _id field which is automatically indexed then the end result would be a compound index. You live and learn.

Answer (score 8):

You would need a separate compound index for the behavior you desire. In general I recommend against using objects as _id because key order is significant in comparisons, so {a:1, b:1} does not equal {b:1, a:1}. Since not all drivers preserve key order in objects it is very easy to shoot yourself in the foot by doing something like this:

```
db.foo.save(db.foo.findOne())
```